# ToolbarRunGroup button in new UI (IntelliJ Plugin development)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin

I developed a plugin for Android Studio that adds a custom button to the ToolBar. After updating to the new UI the button is not displayed anymore. The plugin is still installed and enabled. Also i couldn't find any errors in idea.log.

The button is part of the ToolbarRunGroup and shows as the first item.

```
<action
        id="RunCustom"
        class="com.example.runcustom"
        description="Run custom Emulator"
        icon="/ic_example">
  <add-to-group group-id="ToolbarRunGroup" anchor="first"/>
</action>
```

My first guess was that ToolbarRunGroup might not be the correct group-id anymore as there was quite a change in the UI of the ToolbarRunGroup on the new UI.

Anyone has an idea what I have to change to make my plugin compatible to the new UI?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I have the same requirement, but can't see how to maintain my existing behaviour with the new UI

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: use the `group-id` `MainToolbarRight` for the new IntelliJ UI, where you would use `ToolbarRunGroup` for the old

(In practice you will likely want to contribute to both, to support both)

Took some finding, but see the comment here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298614/newUI-breaks-Flutter-plugin-device-selector#focus=Comments-27-6723690.0-0